# How do you use minted to render a code block in monospaced font with all black text?

Tags: minted, code, sourcecode

How do you use minted to render a code block in teletype font (monospace fixed width font) and all text is the same color (probably black)?

What would you write if you wanted all text to be black inside of the code-block (no syntax highlighting.

We do **not** want:

```
\usemintedstyle{perldoc}      
\usemintedstyle{colorful}
```

---

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{myblack}{black!50!white}

\begin{document}

\section*{Minted styles with non-italic comments}

\subsection*{Light theme}

\subsubsection*{\texttt{perldoc}}

\usemintedstyle{perldoc}

\begin{minted}[linenos]{r}


    int main():
        // Generate data
        const unsigned arraySize = 32768;
        
       // arraySize = 32768
       // arraySize = const(unsigned(arraySize))
        
        Array<int> data = Array<int>(arraySize);

        for (unsigned k = 0; k < arraySize; ++k)
            data[k] = k;
            // semi-colon ; and new line \n is redundant
            // \n\r;  ... three consecutive infix operators 
            // \r\n;  ... three consecutive infix operators
            // \n;    ... two consecutive infix operator
            // ;      ... one consecutive infix operator 
            // \n     ... one consecutive infix operator

        //TO DO: randomize order

        // TO DO: TEST TIME FOR LINEAR Searchinf for
        // arraySize/2 

        data.sort();
        // Equivalent to:
        //      sort(data);
        //      sort<<Array<int>>>(data);  
        //      sort<type(data)>(data); 

    // TO DO: Binary Search 
    Uni<float> start   = Unitized<float>(clock(), "seconds");
    Uni<float> current = Unitized<float>(clock(), "seconds");

    // `Uni` is sub_sequence alias of `Unitized`
    // all sequence are allowed provided that
    // not exist two labels in current scope
    // such that alias is subsequence of both labels

    Uni<unsigned> = Uni<unsigned>duration(5, "min");  

    // most case-insensitive sub-sequences of "min" are allowed
    // as string inputs to the Unitized template constructor

    while (current - start < ideal_duration):
        // TO DO: 
        //     run binary search
        //     count number of binary searches were done

        // ENGLISH:
        //    promote integer to Unitized<insigned>("seconds")
        current = clock();
    
    actual_duration = finish - start
    
    average_time = count/actual_duration 
    

       
       // colon `:` at end of loop preamble 
       //           is redundant
       //
       // the following two things are the same
       //     for():for()
       //     for()for()
       //
       // the following two things are the same
       //     pow:(10, 99)
       //     pow(10, 99)
       //
       // colon is an infix delimieter (and comma, space, etc...)
       //
       // transition from alphanumeric chars to non-alphanumeric
       // is implicit infix delimeter
       //
       // `for` is a functor
       // ---------------
       // for(x)(y)
       // ---------------
       // f = for(x)
       // f(y)
       // ---------------

    std::cout << average_time << '\n';

        //std::cout similar to
        //   disp()
        //   display()
        //   print()
        //   printf()
        //   fprintf()

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you use minted if you don't want syntax highlighting? A simple verbatim or lstlisting would be much easier and would not require external tools. Using minted seems like overkill.

Comment: given the only purpose for minted is to syntax highlight the listing, "don't use minted" is the simplest answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `bw` style for a black and white result (run `pygmentize -L styles` to get a list of all the default styles available):

```
% !TeX program = txs:///arara
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: on, interaction: nonstopmode, shell: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{myblack}{black!50!white}

%\selectcolormodel{gray}

\begin{document}

\section*{Minted styles with non-italic comments}

\subsection*{Light theme}

\subsubsection*{\texttt{perldoc}}

\usemintedstyle{bw}

\begin{minted}[linenos]{r}


    int main():
        // Generate data
        const unsigned arraySize = 32768;
        
       // arraySize = 32768
       // arraySize = const(unsigned(arraySize))
        
        Array<int> data = Array<int>(arraySize);

        for (unsigned k = 0; k < arraySize; ++k)
            data[k] = k;
            // semi-colon ; and new line \n is redundant
            // \n\r;  ... three consecutive infix operators 
            // \r\n;  ... three consecutive infix operators
            // \n;    ... two consecutive infix operator
            // ;      ... one consecutive infix operator 
            // \n     ... one consecutive infix operator

        //TO DO: randomize order

        // TO DO: TEST TIME FOR LINEAR Searchinf for
        // arraySize/2 

        data.sort();
        // Equivalent to:
        //      sort(data);
        //      sort<<Array<int>>>(data);  
        //      sort<type(data)>(data); 

    // TO DO: Binary Search 
    Uni<float> start   = Unitized<float>(clock(), "seconds");
    Uni<float> current = Unitized<float>(clock(), "seconds");

    // `Uni` is sub_sequence alias of `Unitized`
    // all sequence are allowed provided that
    // not exist two labels in current scope
    // such that alias is subsequence of both labels

    Uni<unsigned> = Uni<unsigned>duration(5, "min");  

    // most case-insensitive sub-sequences of "min" are allowed
    // as string inputs to the Unitized template constructor

    while (current - start < ideal_duration):
        // TO DO: 
        //     run binary search
        //     count number of binary searches were done

        // ENGLISH:
        //    promote integer to Unitized<insigned>("seconds")
        current = clock();
    
    actual_duration = finish - start
    
    average_time = count/actual_duration 
    

       
       // colon `:` at end of loop preamble 
       //           is redundant
       //
       // the following two things are the same
       //     for():for()
       //     for()for()
       //
       // the following two things are the same
       //     pow:(10, 99)
       //     pow(10, 99)
       //
       // colon is an infix delimieter (and comma, space, etc...)
       //
       // transition from alphanumeric chars to non-alphanumeric
       // is implicit infix delimeter
       //
       // `for` is a functor
       // ---------------
       // for(x)(y)
       // ---------------
       // f = for(x)
       // f(y)
       // ---------------

    std::cout << average_time << '\n';

        //std::cout similar to
        //   disp()
        //   display()
        //   print()
        //   printf()
        //   fprintf()

\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

First off, *don't* indent verbatim-like environments, because that indentation would be preserved in the output.

Second, if you don't want special formatting, use `Verbatim`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\section*{Minted styles with non-italic comments}

\begin{minted}[style=bw,linenos]{r}
int main():
    // Generate data
    const unsigned arraySize = 32768;

    // arraySize = 32768
    // arraySize = const(unsigned(arraySize))
    Array<int> data = Array<int>(arraySize);

    for (unsigned k = 0; k < arraySize; ++k)
        data[k] = k;
        // semi-colon ; and new line \n is redundant
        // \n\r;  ... three consecutive infix operators 
        // \r\n;  ... three consecutive infix operators
        // \n;    ... two consecutive infix operator
        // ;      ... one consecutive infix operator 
        // \n     ... one consecutive infix operator
\end{minted}

\section*{Simple verbatim}

\begin{Verbatim}[linenos]
int main():
    // Generate data
    const unsigned arraySize = 32768;

    // arraySize = 32768
    // arraySize = const(unsigned(arraySize))
    Array<int> data = Array<int>(arraySize);

    for (unsigned k = 0; k < arraySize; ++k)
        data[k] = k;
        // semi-colon ; and new line \n is redundant
        // \n\r;  ... three consecutive infix operators 
        // \r\n;  ... three consecutive infix operators
        // \n;    ... two consecutive infix operator
        // ;      ... one consecutive infix operator 
        // \n     ... one consecutive infix operator
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

If you insist with `minted` and you want *all* listings to use `bw`, just issue `\usemintedstyle{bw}` in the preamble.

[image]